# How to connect two rails projects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I created two rails apps `sample` and `test`. There are two databases. `users` table in `sample` app with the field `report_id` refers to `reports` table in `test` app.

I want to display the `test` app data in `sample` app by fetching the `unique_id` field. I want to display `reports` data for a particular user by connecting these two databases.

How can I achieve this in the simplest way?

Comment: check if this can help you http://imnithin.github.io/multiple-database.html

Answer (score 1):

For rails6, you can provide two connections and specify databases for each connection, 
eg

```
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  username: username
  password: password
  pool: 5
  host: localhost

development:
  primary:
    <<: *default
    database: database1
    adapter: postgresql
  secondary:
    <<: *default
    database: database2
    adapter: postgresql
```

and for production environment, you can use database url's like

```
  primary:
    url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>

  secondary:
    url: <%= ENV['SECONDARY_DATABASE_URL'] %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to two databases from each rails project:

```
#config/sabple_database.yml
default: &default  
  encoding: utf8
  adapter: mysql2
  port: 5500

development:  
  <<: *default
  database: sample_db
  host:
  username:
  password:


#config/initializers/sample_database.rb
SAMPLE_DB = YAML.load_file(File.join(Rails.root, "config", "sample_database.yml"))[Rails.env.to_s]

#models
class SampleDbBase < ActiveRecord::Base  
  self.abstract_class = true
  establish_connection SAMPLE_DB
end

#models/my_model.rb
class MyModel < SampleDbBase 
end
```

Read [more about that](https://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/managing-multiple-databases-in-a-single-rails-application/). So, then you can create the same models without migration(allows using `Reports.find(report_id)`).

Also, you can write a query to some database using [`ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/establish_connection/class) and `execute`.

Comment: Instead of connecting 2 databases in a rails project, can we fetch the data using HTTP url? Eg: http://localhost:3000/get_reports/id

Comment: @ShruthiR, of course possible write some methods as API for each app and make communication between both via API requests. In this case, you must check what data are secret. If some data are secret, need to use some authentication for your servers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to rails 6. multi DB connection will come default from rails 6.
Please use GitHub version of rails. and configure the database.yml:

```
development:
  primary:
  <<: *default
  database: multiple_databases_development
  animals:
  <<: *default
  database: multiple_databases_development_animals
  migrations_paths: "db/animals_migrate"
```

For more detail please have a look at https://github.com/eileencodes/multiple_databases_demo